# Not able to extract value from a form array Angular 8

Tags: angular

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a29jfx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
This is my demo, in this demo I am not able to extract skill value, suppose i enter details and put value for skill as "1", then in my console it should display "1". I tried using map but it returns value in an array, and i dont need value in an array.
In my demo for ts line 76, I have tried to extract the skill, bit it comes as undefined don't know why, please help.

Comment: Post relevant code here

Comment: What do you want to return when there are more than one skill?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a29jfx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts  ..in my demo I have body, so when ever submitit pressed, i want it to update it in the body, I am just not able to get values fro skill and exp, i want skill and exp values separately as I need to manipulate them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the `.value` property when accessing the values. Try the following

```js
  // If you need to get all skills of an employee as an array.
  getEmployeeSkills(index: number){
    const employee  = this.empForm.value.employees[index]
    if (employee === undefined) return null
    return employee.skills.length === 0 ? null : employee.skills.map(skill => skill.skill);
  }

  // OR

  // Access specific skill of an employee
  getEmployeeSkill(employeeIdx: number, skillIdx: number) {
    const employee  = this.empForm.value.employees[employeeIdx];
    if (employee === undefined) return null
    return employee.skills.length === 0 ? null : employee.skills.map(skill => skill.skill)[skillIdx];
  }
```

It can then be called as

```js
console.log("skills of employee 0 is ", this.getEmployeeSkills(0));
console.log("skill 0 of employee 0 is ", this.getEmployeeSkill(0, 0));
console.log("skill 1 of employee 0 is ", this.getEmployeeSkill(0, 1));

// NOTE: `this.getEmployeeSkill(0, 0)` is the same as `this.getEmployeeSkills(0)[0]`
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rb7jno)

Comment: this worked, but when i try to put it in my const body{}, it does not update, how do i make the indexes update when add employee or add skills is pressed, i was all the info to be displayed in the body, i am only get 0th index employee div and 0th index skills div..please help..  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cuukb4